# Where do I put the Javascript for creating Cordova plugins?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I've been playing around with Cordova, and I've been following [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) documentation to learn how to create the sample plugin. However, I'm confused as to where I have to put the Javascript at the beginning of the documentation. Any help would be appreciated! I'm also using iOS with Xcode. 
Thanks!
~Carpefizz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put them in the  header of index.html or add a separate  header to index.html and include the scripts in a separate .js file. Make sure to read all the documentation you can find!

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Cordova being relatively new doesn't have much documentation apart from the ones provided. Also, it splits up the two scripts saying ` Plugin users would then use it as follows:` Does that mean that the user doesn't write/see the part where it defines `window.echo` ?

Comment: That's right. The first part of that script is part of the plug-in. The second part calls the first part. The user shouldn't have to bother with the first part.

Comment: cool, and where would I put the first part? Would they just have to include the javascript containing it? Thanks again.

Comment: You put the first part anywhere, where it can be made available to the second part. The first part is the script that is in the <script> tag or in the .js file. The second part is anywhere in the html.index file, calling the first part. The first part is like a gateway to the native Objective-C code. It all becomes clear when you click any of the links at the bottom of that page and keep reading about the native implementation.